# Is there a way to validate text in Angular Material Dialog box using Cypress?

Tags: angular-material, cypress, material-dialog

I want to read and validate the text inside an Angular Material Dialogue box using Cypress. But I am facing a problem as Cypress is not identifying the Dialogue box at all, hence not even able to click on the button inside the dialogue box. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried along with some examples of how your DOM looks like ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not identifying the Dialogue box at all"? It may be that your Material Dialogue is within a #shadow-root (or something similar). Try using cypress.get('page-identifier').shadow().find('elementOnDialogue').